# How can I log file access from users?

Tags: files, users, log

I have to give someone access to my computer, but I want to know afterwards which files he accessed... Can I create a log file for that? Is there an existing program for that? I know how to track processes but I just want the files accessed by one user.

Answer (score 4):

### Using `iwatch`

`iwatch` **o_O** is a *realtime filesystem monitoring program using inotify*
 and a working local mail service

---

For a better obscurity you should change the mail address and start the deamon as root, or something else … **:)**

---

```
sudo apt-get install iwatch
```

1. Create a configuration file with the name `iwatch.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "/etc/iwatch/iwatch.dtd" >
   <config>
           <guard email="username@localhost" name="iWatch"/>
           <watchlist>
                   <title>a title</title>
                   <contactpoint email="username@localhost" name="foo bar"/>
                   <path type="recursive" events="default">/home/username</path>
           </watchlist>
   </config>
   ```
2. Start the deamon

   ```
   iwatch -d -f iwatch.xml -p ~/iwatch.pid
   ```

   `-d` Execute the application as daemon. iWatch will run in foregroud without this option.

   `-f` Specify alternative configuration file. Default is `/etc/iwatch/iwatch.xml`

   `-p` Specify an alternate pid file. Default: `/var/run/iwatch.pid`
3. Check your local mails **;)**

---

```
Some interesting events

-e event [,event[,..]]
   Specify a list of events you want to watch. Following are the possible events you
   can use:
access          : file was modified
modify          : file was modified
attrib          : file attributes changed
close_write     : file closed, after being opened in writeable mode
close_nowrite   : file closed, after being opened in read-only mode
close           : file closed, regardless of read/write mode
open            : file was opened
moved_from      : File was moved away from.
moved_to        : File was moved to.
move            : a file/dir within watched directory was moved
create          : a file was created within watched director
delete          : a file was deleted within watched directory
delete_self     : the watched file was deleted
unmount         : file system on which watched file exists was unmounted
q_overflow      : Event queued overflowed
ignored         : File was ignored
isdir           : event occurred against dir
oneshot         : only send event once
all_events      : All events
default         : close_write, create, delete, move, delete_self and move_self.
```

---

More information [here](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/documentation.html)

Comment: is there a way to stop it from emailing anybody and just execute command?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I'm not sure. The guard tag is necessary but maybe you could use an other attribute.

Comment: maybe you research for me >:)

Comment: won't say what user accessed the file

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel - badly.

Use auditing.  Tracking who accesses what files is **exactly** what auditing is for.

A good link to get started is [here](http://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/).

> **Auditing goals**
>
> By using a powerful audit framework, the system can track many event
>   types to monitor and audit the system. Examples include:
>
> - Audit file access and modification
>
>   - See who changed a particular file
>   - Detect unauthorized changes
> - Monitoring of system calls and functions
> - Detect anomalies like crashing processes
> - Set tripwires for intrusion detection purposes
> - Record commands used by individual users

Answer (score 1):

### Using `find`

The following solution works not with deleted files and, if you have **not** set `noatime` in your fstab, eg:

```
defaults,noatime
```

---

Using `find` after you have your account back.

```
find ~ -atime -1
```

means, accessed less than 1 day.

Or a combination:

```
find ~ -atime 1 -atime -2
```

means 1-2 days ago

---

from `man find`

```
-atime n
      File  was  last  accessed n*24 hours ago.  When find figures
      out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed,
      any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file
      has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

-amin n
      File was last accessed n minutes ago.
```

Comment: Nice, but you must also either set the `atime` attribute to the files to track prior the access (using `chattr`) or mount the file system with the `atime` option: http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html

Comment: @kos I thought, `defaults` includes `atime`

Comment: The act of deleting files is not solved with this ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Umpf, you're right.

Comment: Maybe inotify. But that probably works on a per file... so that will be lots of work :(

Comment: @kos, you can recycle your answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/615435/367165

Comment: I don't know, now I can't, if you want to recycle it I won't mind, you gave the same answer as well! I'm trying to figure out which is the default behavior for `atime` in Ubuntu but I'm not on Ubuntu right now, on Debian `atime` is not changed for a simple read, if you want to test it on Ubuntu I used this: `ls -l --time=atime`

Comment: Works in Ubuntu, tested.

Comment: Ok +1 then, if you want to add the inoticoming thing you should feel free tough!

Comment: @kos I'm not sure if it works with sub-folders.

Comment: @Rinzwind see my other answer =)

Comment: No, probably not, or too much hassle to work out a solution.